# Angular Nested Controllers Dependent Service Calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi Have nested angular controllers.  The outer controller is a personController and the inner controller is a personScheduleController.  The person controller makes a service call to get person data.  The personScheduleController makes a service call to get person schedule data, however, it is dependent upon the data returned from the person data service call.  What is the best way to do this in angular?  Should I make the initial person data service call synchronous?

Answer (score 0):

On reception of person data you can use `$rootscope.$broadcast('person-data', data)` to the send person data and the scheduler controller of receive it by

```
$rootscope.$on('person-data', function (event, data) {
})
```